# How can I get the dispatch service name?

Tags: python, microservices, nameko

Using nameko, I have a `green_event` that can be dispatched by two different services:

```
@event_handler("service1", "green_event")
@event_handler("service2", "green_event")
def green_event(self, payload):
   # ...
   # ...
```

How can I get the variable with the service name?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution might be to split the handler entrypoints:

```
@event_handler("service1", "green_event")
def green_event_service1(self, payload):
    self.green_event("service1", payload)

@event_handler("service2", "green_event")
def green_event_service2(self, payload):
    self.green_event("service2", payload)

def green_event(self, source, payload):
   # ...
```